# the application requires that assembly microsoft.reportviewer.processingObjectModel version 11.0.0.0 be installed in the global assembly cache first

Tags: .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, gac

I have a small windows forms application created in Visual Studio 2012 that uses ReportViewer version 11.0.0.0.

The application target framework is .NET 4.0 and its deployment method is ClickOnce

On my PC it installs but on client machines, intallation fails with error

***the application requires that assembly microsoft.reportviewer.processingObjectModel version 11.0.0.0 be installed in the global assembly cache first.***

On the client machines, i have installed

- .NET 4.0
- ReportViewer 2010
- Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime CTP
- SQLSYSCLRTYPES.msi

in the project application files settings, i have set **microsoft.reportviewer.processingObjectModel** ***publish status*** to **Include(Auto)**, in the references i have also set its ***Copy Local*** property to **True**.

what am i missing?

I have even followed the instructions here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing the ProcessingObjectModel.dll file find the version 11.0.0.0 in gac assembly C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel and add it to bin dir.

Answer (score 21):

Here is (arguably) the best way to deal with this issue... without downloading or installing any extras. This worked with Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate)

1. Goto the main project within your solution(default/statup project)
2. Right Click and Click Properties / Select "Your Project">> Project>> Properties
3. Click on "Publish" Tab to see publishing options
4. Goto "Install Mode and Settings">> Click "Application Files" and Dialog opens
5. Go down and look for the items set with "Publish Status" > Prerequisite
6. You will find ReportViewer and Several Other Files set to Prerequisite
7. Change all the Publish Statuses to "Include" in the drop down
8. I know you only need the ReportViewer Only but this will eliminate other potential problems I came across
9. Now all the required files will be added to your installation setup good to go!
10. For interest, you can change include a desktop icon under "Install Mode and Settings">>Options>Mainfests>Create Desktop Short Cut

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue, but the thing is, its automatically adding it to the references (microsoft.reportviewer.processingObjectModel), if u EXCLUDE it from the publishing properties(properties->publish->application files), It might fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using WinForms, to me it seems pointless to worry about installing this DLL in the GAC when it's being used for a report viewer that is deployed via click-once. This isn't a big file and you're probably using it as a report viewer control on a form, nothing more. One possible solution is to do the following:

1. In Visual Studio, go to the reference in your project for the assembly `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel`and locate the file path to the folder for that assembly. Mine was version 12 and so my file path was `C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91`
2. Copy the file path of the folder the assembly is in and remove the reference from your project (right click the reference and select "Remove").
3. Win + R to get a 'Run' prompt. Paste that folder path in there and execute to jump right into the folder of that DLL.
4. Find the DLL, it should be the only file in that folder, and copy it to your Visual Studio project folder. You shouldn't care about 100kb of extra space on your drive consumed, and I don't think this DLL is one you'll need to update.
5. Back in Visual Studio, right click References, Add Reference, and browse for that DLL in your project folder. After adding the reference, make sure that the Copy Local property is set to true.
6. Clean and rebuild, test the application on your local computer, than Deploy your ClickOnce again.

Now when users install your application with ClickOnce, the reference will not refer to the GAC at all and there won't be any need to rely on the prerequisite check/installation process for this DLL because you have included it directly in your published application.

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to install the Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package at:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6610

Your users will need to have this package installed as well.  If you just copy and paste a MS DLL, you'll have to redeploy it every time you upgrade your application.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the setup type you are using but basically, it means the required library is missing from your server or computer. To enable the application to download from the server (In a client-server architecture), you need to include the file(s) in the project.

1. Go to your application option and locate the "Publish" tab
2. Click on "Application files"
3. In the ensuing dialog, select to include all the libraries you want included (or that are required to run your application on the client machine and click "Ok")
4. Build your application and then publish to the server.

I hope this works for you, it worked for me in Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Answer (score 0):

In case of Windows 10 it won't work installing Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 SP1 as describe by user1236560. First you need to install Prerequisites for SQL Server Management Objects (SQLSysClrTypes.msi) need to choose between x86 and x64 depending on your hardware. You could find it on: http://origin.www.ms.akadns.net/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=16BC778C-357B-46E9-8356-D575903AC831

After that you need to install MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME that you could find on: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747

Both of this package will have to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error

---

System Update Required

Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel Version 11.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

Please contact your system administrator.

---

this error popped out when installing an application made from Visual Studio
meaning I am one of the client

I have Visual Studio 2015 and a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and didn't know about Crystal Reports and other related stuff to it. I do check the version of my .NET Framework which is version 4.6.2.

I have several extension files and distributable files downloaded and yet doesn't solve my problem.

**I do not know if I solve the problem generally but I do become successful in installing the application**

so I downloaded and installed the ff:

- SAP Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2015(latest, just to make sure)
- Microsoft System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server 2012
- Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime.

the problem took me about 2 days to trouble shoot, Be careful on downloading and installing extension files and distributed files cause it will munch some space too.

Answer (score -2):

The Best answer is:

Here is (arguably) the best way to deal with this issue... without downloading or installing any extras. This worked with Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate)

1. Go to the main project within your solution(default/statup project)
2. Right Click and Click Properties / Select "Your Project">> Project>> Properties
3. Click on "Publish" Tab to see publishing options
4. Go to "Install Mode and Settings">> Click "Application Files" and Dialog opens
5. Go down and look for the items set with "Publish Status" > Prerequisite
   You will find ReportViewer and Several Other Files set to Prerequisite
6. Change all the Publish Statuses to "Include" in the drop down.

I know you only need the ReportViewer Only but this will eliminate other potential problems I came across
Now all the required files will be added to your installation setup good to go!

For interest, you can change include a desktop icon under "Install Mode and Settings">>Options>Mainfests>Create Desktop Short Cut

It reduced all of my head aches.