# Clickonce Fails when publishing from one machine but is successful when publishing from another

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a clickonce application.  I have my current workstation set up, but when I publish from there my users receive an error

```
"Unable to install or run the application.  The application rqeuires that Microsoft.SqlServer.Types Version 12.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first."
```

If I publish from my old work station, my users do not receive this error.

Both work stations are connected to the same TFS server, so I'm reasonable sure they are in sync.  I also checked the Application Files section under the publish tab and verified that they have the same settings.  They also have the same Copy Local option in the Reference Properties.

If I remove the reference, I just run into another reference with the same issue.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked out a somewhat [related issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476814/the-application-requires-that-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-processingobjectmo) ?

Comment: Is that answer saying I'm missing it from the machine I'm publishing from?  Or that the client machine is missing it?

Comment: Actually, this pointed me in the correct direction, thank you.  The issue is that the newer machine has a later version of these libraries in the GAC that the old machine.  But the old machine is in sync with the client machines.  So the new machine will try to push V12, the old pushes out V10, the client has V10.

Comment: Good, glad you got it figured out!